# Is it a bad idea to use synchronous filesystem methods in a Dart web server?

Tags: asynchronous, webserver, dart, blocking

I'm playing around with HttpServer; and was adding support for serving static files (I'm aware of Shelf; I'm doing this as a learning exercise). I have a list of handlers that are given the opportunity to handle the request in sequence (stopping at the first that handles it):

```dart
const handlers = const [
  handleStaticRequest
];

handleRequest(HttpRequest request) {
  // Run through all handlers; and if none handle the request, 404
  if (!handlers.any((h) => h(request))) {
    request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    request.response.headers.contentType = new ContentType("text", "html");
    request.response.write('<h1>404 File Not Found</h1>');
    request.response.close();
  }
}
```

However, as I implemented the static file handler, I realised that I couldn't return true/false directly (which is required by the handleRequest code above, to signal if the request is handled) unless I use file.existsSync().

In something like ASP.NET, I wouldn't think twice about a blocking call in a request because it's threaded; however in Dart, it seems like it would be a bottleneck if every request is blocking every other request for the duration of IO hits like this.

So, I decided to have a look in Shelf, to see how that handled this; but disappointingly, that [appears to do the same](https://github.com/kevmoo/shelf_static.dart/blob/master/lib/src/static_handler.dart#L51) (in fact, it does several synchronous filesystem hits).

Am I overestimating the impact of this; or is this a bad idea for a Dart web service? I'm not writing Facebook; but I'd still like to learn to write things in the most efficient way.

If this is considered bad; is there a built-in way of doing "execute these futures sequentially until the first one returns a match for this condition"? I can see Future.forEach but that doesn't have the ability to bail. I guess "Future.any" is probably what it'd be called if it existed (but that doesn't)?

Comment: I think you could use something like `new Future.wait(handlers.map((h)  => h())` where `handleStaticRequest()` returns a future.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The problem is, that will execute all of the handlers; I believe I should run them sequentially, stopping on the first that handles the request.

Comment: I see. I assume quiver has some helper methods to simplify that in async code but I haven't used this package much yet and don't know which function/class provides that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Aha! I hadn't seen that, but looks like quiver's Future.doWhileAsync does just what I want!

Comment: Ok, you don't even need quiver then :-)

Comment: `doWhileAsync` is from quiver. Doesn't seem to be a built-in equivalent :(

Comment: Ok, they named the class `Future` too.

Comment: Actually, I typed it badly! The sig is `Future doWhileAsync`, I put a dot where I shouldn't have!

Comment: Seems like `quiver` might not be needed after all; there's a `Stream.fromIterable` constructor and an `asyncMap` which seems to do the stepping through as I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of good questions in your post (perhaps we should split them out into individual SO questions?).

To answer the post title's question, the best practice for *servers* is to use the async methods.

For command-line utilities and simple scripts, the sync methods are perfectly fine.

Comment: That's what I thought; but I was a bit thrown by Kevin Moore's use of the sync methods in Shelf. I've managed to make this work async nicely now; might do a perf test of the differences and write it up for my blog if I get chance!

Answer (score 3):

Using [Shelf](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf) is the right approach here.

But there is still a trade-off between sync and async within the static handler package.

Blocking on I/O obviously limits concurrency, but there is a non-zero cost to injecting `Future` into a code path.

<del>I will dig in a bit to get a better answer here.</del>

After doing some investigation, it **does not** seem that adding async I/O in the `shelf_static` improves performance **except for the bit that's already async: reading file contents**.

`return new Response.ok(file.openRead(), headers: headers);`

The actual reading of file contents is done by passing a `Stream` to the response. This ensures that the bulk of the slow I/O happens in a non-blocking way. This is key.

In the mean time, you may want to look at [Future.forEach](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Future#id_doWhile) for an easy way to invoke an arbitrary number of async methods.

Comment: Future.forEach doesn't allow short cutting; but I managed it with Stream.fromIterable().mapAsync().any or similar :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it becomes a problem if you do file access that is blocking for a long time (reading/writing/searching big files locally or over the network).
I can't imagine `file.existsSync()` doing much damage. If you are already in async code it's easy to stay async but if you have to go async just for the sake of not using `file.existsSync()` I would consider this premature optimization.

Comment: I don't think `existSync` is expensive; I'm just trying to understand best practices. If you're blocking requests on IO, it means you're wasting CPU that could be serving requests, and that does not sound at all scale-friendly.

Comment: This could be offset by running more web servers than you have cores; but based on the isolate-web-server stuff I saw; it seemed the expectation is one-isolate-per-core :/

Comment: I think you need to do benchmarks to be sure. I think I remember that calling async methods sometimes causes more CPU usage than sync because of some overhead but I don't remember where that was - I guess some comments on issues on http://dartbug.com. I think this question is an issue with no simple answer, it is more an 'it depends' - on what your app is actually doing and where the bottlenecks are. What's the point if you do all async and the disk doesn't return the data in time and your app has to wait anyway?

Comment: That's the whole point of using async and callbacks. If it takes 0.1s to read the file from disk; using the synchronous method means every request is blocked for 0.1s needlessly. Using the async method means the thread is used by other requests while the IO occurs. This isn't about speeding up a single request, it's about not blocking the CPU for *all inbound requests* while disk IO is happening. Blocking your entire web server for a disk read does not seem in any way sensible for a real app. (However, Shelf does this, which is what's making my question my understanding!)

Comment: I understand that but when the disk isn't fast enough the only effect by calling this async might be that you can have more 'threads' waiting simultaneously for disk I/O and if you do disk I/O sync they would just wait somewhere else (tcp connect or whatever). Therefore I think you need to analyze the behavior of the application in real world scenarios to see where the bottlenecks really are.

Comment: Ofcourse if the disk throughput is too low, your server is going to fail, but that's expected. However even when your disk is fine and fast; synchronous IO in the *only thread* is just wasting CPU cycles, which will surely lower throughput unnecessarily? Maybe the exists check is fast; but what about the actual reading of the file contents when it exists? You don't want every static request (gifs, css, js, html) causing your CPU to sit twiddling its thumbs when there are requests? Sure, this isn't going to be an issue for everyone; I'm just trying to ensure I understand correctly.

Comment: I'm not a specialist in this topic and curious myself whether someone else has a different opinion. I like being proven wrong when I learn something new in exchange ;-)

Comment: Looks like NodeJS also has sync methods; so this same question applies there. I found [this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint.github.io/blob/master/docs/rules/no-sync.md), but not much more on this topic :(

Comment: Oh, and [this from LinkedIn](http://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile), "When you do, the impact on performance is dramatic." "one synchronous call caused a performance drop from thousands of requests per second to just a few dozen!"

Comment: I wouldn't do file read/write of files bigger than a few bytes sync (also only relevant for code that is executed often) but as your linked doc suggests - use something like ngingx or CDN for serving static content. There shouldn't be much file access left over in your Dart code. Network access like database access should be done async in any case.

Comment: In many(most?) cases these days "disk access" is effectively "network access"; I don't think we should make exceptions for disks. IO is IO; and it'll likely stall and flake randomly :D

Comment: For me it just comes down to: Use async for I/O and avoid sync but it's your decision as developer/architect to make exceptions and it's wise to do performance tests to verify that it doesn't hurt thoughput. It's basically the same as 'never use goto' we have learned/heard/read so often. In compiler lessions at university the code we built had a lot of gotos and was considered fine because it had hurt performance and increased code complexity if we'd have avoided `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

A little offtopick, but it solved my problem, I was trying to solve by reading discussion on this question. I was not able to achieve async operation in handler with io.serve, so I used dart:io for active pages and shelf.handleReguest for static files:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async' show runZoned;
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join, dirname;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'package:shelf_static/shelf_static.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:sqljocky/sqljocky.dart';

void main(){
HttpServer
     .bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 9999)
     .then((server) {
       server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
         String path = request.requestedUri.path;
         if(path == "/db"){
           var pool = new ConnectionPool(host: 'localhost', port: 3306, user: 'root', db: 'db', max: 5);
                 var result = pool.query("select * from myTable");
                   result.then((Results data) {
                     data.first.then((Row row) {
                       request.response.write(row.toString());
                       request.response.close();
                     });
                   });
         }else{
           String pathToBuild = join(dirname(Platform.script.toFilePath()), '..', 'build/web');
           var handler = createStaticHandler(pathToBuild, defaultDocument: 'index.html');
           io.handleRequest(request, handler);
         }
       });
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many months later I've found how to create that Stream... (still offtopick .. a little)

```
shelf.Response _echoRequest(shelf.Request request) {
       StreamController controller = new StreamController();
       Stream<List<int>> out = controller.stream;
       new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:1)).then((_){ 
              controller.add(const Utf8Codec().encode("hello"));
              controller.close();
       });
       return new shelf.Response.ok(out);
}
```